# Quasi Experiment with Diff-in-diff but very uneven # of treatment and control sample

Tags: difference-in-difference, propensity-scores, observational-study

Let's say my app has 1M users and I launched a new feature in the app. As a result of this launch 10K users (1%) adopted this new feature. I want to understand the impact of this new feature on average session time.

My question is how we can deal with the unbalanced treatment vs. control here since the ratio is 1:99. Can I first do a 1:99 propensity score matching and then DID? What if the ratio is more extreme like 1:999?

Comment: Welcome to CV. What is your control group in this setting?

Comment: @ThomasBilach my control group here would be all the users who haven't adopted the new feature.